# Is it possible if I create an LSTM model from Keras and followed by a Neural Network from scratch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I want to ask, is it possible if the LSTM model using Keras can be continued with the Neural Network from scratch? here is my coding look like if i use full library instead:

```
visible = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedding = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM, weights = [embedding_matrix], input_length = MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, trainable=False, name = 'embeddings')(visible)
lstm, states_h, states_c = LSTM(60, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, kernel_initializer="random_normal")(embedding)
pooling = GlobalMaxPool1D()(lstm)
hidden = Dense(10, activation='relu')(pooling)
output = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(hidden)
```

From the coding above, is it possible Dense() layer replaced with my own Neural Network from Scratch?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "your own neural network from scratch".

Comment: I made Neural Network from scratch without using the library from Keras @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: Then then answer is no, how would gradients be computed if your network does not use the same backend as Keras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `hidden` is not defined so I don't really know what you want to accomplish here, but I think you should be able to do something like this :

```
visible = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedding = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, EMBEDDING_DIM, weights = [embedding_matrix], input_length = MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, trainable=False, name = 'embeddings')(visible)
lstm, states_h, states_c = LSTM(60, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, kernel_initializer="random_normal")(embedding)
pooling = GlobalMaxPool1D()(lstm)
output = your_model(hidden)
```

You just have to make sure the shapes of your model are corresponding with `hidden`

EDIT : I didn't see you wanted to make a model from scratch. Then you have to make a custom keras layer, which is well explained here : https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/